# How to display the value get from .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this code here but it doesn't work... I have a text input where user can key in any number. When user click on ADD, it will add a new row to the table. when click on REMOVE, that row will be remove.

I want to keep track of the index and it is working. However I need to keep track of the number the user input as well, then I can remove that row with that number. However, I can't get the `textInput` to be displayed on the table... not sure what's the right way to display that. Please help.

```
 var index=1;
 textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();

 $('#outputAdd').click(function(){
                   index++;
                   $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_'+textInput+'"><td>'+index+'</td><td id="type_row_'+index+'">type_row_'+textInput+'</td><td id="num_row_'+index+'">num row '+index+'</td><td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td></tr>');
                });
  $('#outputRemove').click(function(){

                    $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_'+textInput+'").remove();
               });
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
$('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_'+textInput+'").remove();
```

With this:

```
$('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_" + textInput).remove();
```

and try again!

Comment: yay it works! but how do i display it for this <td id="type_row_'+index+'">type_row_'+textInput+'</td> ? it will appear as type_row_textInput...

Comment: i want to display it in the table but that line showed "#type_row_" + index

Comment: Not able to get you properly. You might add it to your question as an update, with more explanation!

Comment: as in the codes you showed me ($('#status_table').find("#type_row_" + index).show();) printed this ' "#type_row_" + index ' literally on the screen.