# How do I do a switch case for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this if-else statement which gave me weird response... whenever i select "output" first, nothing else selected afterwards can appear... 
FYI, I am using multi select so I can select and show as many as I want.

```
 $('#outputText').hide();
    $('#armCB').hide();
    $('#outputCB').hide();
    $('#zoneText').hide();
    $('#counterText').hide();
    $('#flagText').hide();
    $('#sensorText').hide();

('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
        if ($('#output').is(':selected')){
            $('#outputText').show();
        }
        else if ($('#arm').is(':selected')){
            $('#armCB').show();
        }
        else if ($('#zone').is(':selected')){
            $('#zoneText').show();
        }
        else if ($('#counter').is(':selected')){
            $('#counterText').show();
        }
        else if ($('#flag').is(':selected')){
            $('#flagText').show();
        }
        else if ($('#sensor').is(':selected')){
            $('#sensorText').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#outputText').hide();
            $('#armCB').hide();
            $('#zoneText').hide();
            $('#counterText').hide();
            $('#flagText').hide();
            $('#sensorText').hide();

        }
```

Is there a mistake in my if-else statement? or must I use Switch case statement here? If so, how should i do it?

HTML:

```
<div id="display" style=" clear:both">
        <div class="left" style="float:left; width:48%">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Select Category</label>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" size="2">

                <option value="arm" id="arm">Arm</option>
                <option value="zone" id="zone">Zone Input</option>
                <option value="output" id="output">Output</option>
                <option value="counter" id="counter">Counter</option>
                <option value="flag" id="flag">Flag</option>
                <option value="sensor" id="sensor">Sensor</option>
            </select>
        </div>



        </div>
        <div class="right" style=" float: right; width:48%">
             <div id="armCB">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>Unit</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="CB" name="armCB_1" id="armCB_1" class="custom" data-mini="true" />
                    <label for="armCB_1">Arming Status</label>
                </fieldset>
             </div>

            <div id="outputText">
                <p> Please enter an Output number and press "Add" button: </p>
                <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="outputTextInput" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="outputAdd" value="Add"/>
                <input type="submit" id="outputRemove" value="Remove"/>
            </div>
            <div id="zoneText">
                <p> Please enter a Zone number and press "Add" button: </p>
                <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="zoneTextInput" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="zoneAdd" value="Add"/>
                <input type="submit" id="zoneRemove" value="Remove"/>
            </div>
            <div id="counterText">
                <p> Please enter a counter number and press "Add" button: </p>
                <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="counterTextInput" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="counterAdd" value="Add"/>
                <input type="submit" id="counterRemove" value="Remove"/>
            </div>
            <div id="flagText">
                <p> Please enter a Flag number and press "Add" button: </p>
                <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="flagTextInput" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="flagAdd" value="Add"/>
                <input type="submit" id="flagRemove" value="Remove"/>
            </div>
            <div id="sensorText">
                <p> Please enter a Sensor number and press "Add" button: </p>
                <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="sensorTextInput" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="sensorAdd" value="Add"/>
                <input type="submit" id="sensorRemove" value="Remove"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is the problem on above if..else if..else?

Comment: @SJnawali it is a multiselect and if i select "output" first, others selected afterwards will not appear.

Answer (score 36):

That`s just standard javascript : 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```
switch(n) {
 case 1:
  //execute code block 1
  break;
 case 2:
  //execute code block 2
  break;
 default:
 // code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

where switch variable will be the name of selected tag

Comment: thanks ... how should i represent "1" as my jquery select statement?

Comment: And can be add multiple case option by omitting break;(s) .

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a switch statement in this case, you can use the current value or id of the selected option for selecting the target element:

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
    $('.elements').hide();
    $('#' + this.value + 'Text').show();
});
```

**Update:**
As you are using multiple attribute for the select element, you can use jQuery `val` method, it returns an array of selected options, then you can create a selector based on the selected values.

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
    $('div.right > div').hide();
    var selector = '#' + $(this).val().join('Text, #') + 'Text';
    $(selector).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3AbJq/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, but changing an ID is not very hard.

Comment: sorry but i just elaborated on my question (i'm using multi select). your codes work but it will not hide or change to another option when i deselect it and select another option.

Comment: it works now (although it seems pretty complicated for me to understand) :D yay! thanks! but what does 'div.right > div' mean?

Comment: @yvonnezoe You are welcome, that's a direct child selector, selects immediate children div elements of the `div`s with class of `right`.

Comment: i see! thank you! as for .join('Text, #'), do u mind to explain this as well? sorry.. i'm very new to java... i saw this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp but it is not in the form of what you've written. i swapped them to become '#, Text' and it stops working. so i'm wondering if there is a reason behind it? :)

Comment: @yvonnezoe Yeah, you mean JavaScript not Java :), for sure, `join` joins the array's elements if the length of the array is more than 1, so if user selects 1 option that option is concatenated with `'Text'`, otherwise it `join`s them with `'Text, #'` and then concatenates it with `'Text'`, you can code `console.log(selector)`, it shows you how selector is created.

Comment: Oh! i got it now! so it is something like #output**Text , #**zoneText. haha that's very interesting :D thank you for the explanation! :) (btw whats the difference between JavaScript and Java? :s )

Comment: @undefined i have another question here if u dont mind :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139196/jquery-assign-and-call-id-with-variable

Comment: @yvonnezoe You are very welcome, actually there are many differences, Java is a general-purpose/server-side language and JavaScript is a client-side/web language. Okay, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **JQuery Switch** statement. If you want to use switch statement you can refer to Javascript Switch.

<kbd>[Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)</kbd>

Here would be my approach. i will add a data-section attribute for each option in #select-choice-1, which will have the id of the corresponding div.

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
        $('#outputText').hide();
        $('#armCB').hide();
        $('#zoneText').hide();
        $('#counterText').hide();
        $('#flagText').hide();
        $('#sensorText').hide();

    //the above hide() methods can be removed if you can
    //add a class for all of these sections and say $('.sectionDivs').hide()
    var divId = $(':selected',this).data('section');
    $('#' + divId ).show();
  
    }
```

Comment: oh thanks! may be you can help me with this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099958/jquery-javascript-how-to-display-the-value-get-from-val/16100003?noredirect=1#comment22989483_16100003 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139196/jquery-assign-and-call-id-with-variable

Answer (score 1):

If it is a multi select, don't use `else if`

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
    $('#outputText').hide();
    $('#armCB').hide();
    $('#zoneText').hide();
    $('#counterText').hide();
    $('#flagText').hide();
    $('#sensorText').hide();

    if ($('#output').is(':selected')) {
        $('#outputText').show();
    }
    if ($('#arm').is(':selected')) {
        $('#armCB').show();
    }
    if ($('#zone').is(':selected')) {
        $('#zoneText').show();
    }
    if ($('#counter').is(':selected')) {
        $('#counterText').show();
    }
    if ($('#flag').is(':selected')) {
        $('#flagText').show();
    }
    if ($('#sensor').is(':selected')) {
        $('#sensorText').show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HNM2u/3/)

You can simplify it to something like below, if you can make some changes to the markup

```
$(function(){

    var $ctitems = $('#select-choice-1-items');
    var $items = $('.item', $ctitems).hide();

    $('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
        $items.hide()
        $('option:selected',this).each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + id + 'Item').show()
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="display" style=" clear:both">
    <div class="left" style="float:left; width:48%">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Select Category</label>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" size="2">
                <option value="arm" id="arm">Arm</option>
                <option value="zone" id="zone">Zone Input</option>
                <option value="output" id="output">Output</option>
                <option value="counter" id="counter">Counter</option>
                <option value="flag" id="flag">Flag</option>
                <option value="sensor" id="sensor">Sensor</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="select-choice-1-items" class="right" style=" float: right; width:48%">
        <div id="armItem" class="item">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Unit</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" class="CB" name="armCB_1" id="armCB_1" class="custom" data-mini="true" />
                <label for="armCB_1">Arming Status</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div id="outputItem" class="item">
            <p> Please enter an Output number and press "Add" button: </p>
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="outputTextInput" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" id="outputAdd" value="Add"/>
            <input type="submit" id="outputRemove" value="Remove"/>
        </div>
        <div id="zoneItem" class="item">
            <p> Please enter a Zone number and press "Add" button: </p>
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="zoneTextInput" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" id="zoneAdd" value="Add"/>
            <input type="submit" id="zoneRemove" value="Remove"/>
        </div>
        <div id="counterItem" class="item">
            <p> Please enter a counter number and press "Add" button: </p>
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="counterTextInput" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" id="counterAdd" value="Add"/>
            <input type="submit" id="counterRemove" value="Remove"/>
        </div>
        <div id="flagItem" class="item">
            <p> Please enter a Flag number and press "Add" button: </p>
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="flagTextInput" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" id="flagAdd" value="Add"/>
            <input type="submit" id="flagRemove" value="Remove"/>
        </div>
        <div id="sensorItem" class="item">
            <p> Please enter a Sensor number and press "Add" button: </p>
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="sensorTextInput" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" id="sensorAdd" value="Add"/>
            <input type="submit" id="sensorRemove" value="Remove"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HNM2u/2/)

Comment: ahh yes that was part of my program which i didnt include in my question above. But the prob is if "output" is selected first, others won't show up. :(

Comment: @yvonnezoe can you share the html also

Comment: @yvonnezoe also try [undefined's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139948/how-do-i-do-a-switch-case-for-jquery/16140092?noredirect=1#answer-16140015)

Comment: okay. i tried undefined's answer but it doesnt work for my case

Comment: @yvonnezoe share the html also

Comment: i've just put up the html :) and no, undefined's answer didn't work for me because i'm using multiple select