# Multiple else if in jQuery

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing dependent select box using jquery, ajax and php from same table of the database. [Testpage](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/staff/sagittarius/filter2.php)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.action').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
       var action = $(this).attr("id");
       var query = $(this).val();
       var result = '';
    
       if(action == "name") {
        result = 'category';
           alert ('test1');
           
       } else if (action == "category")  { 
        result = 'material';
           alert ('test2');
           
       } else if (action == "material")  { 
        result = 'source_light'; 
           alert ('test3');
           
       } else if (action == "source_light")  { 
       result = 'color_temperature';    
           alert ('test4');   
       } else {
         // result = 'color_temperature'; 
       }
          
       $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_filter2.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, query:query},
        success:function(data){
         $('#'+result).html(data);
        }
       })
      }
     });
    });
```

I don't know why but it only works: test1 and test2. Test3 and 4 are not sent to php.

**HTML** file

Maybe something is wrong with select box? But these are just a select box with id's.

```
 <select name="name" id="name" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <?php echo $name; ?>
   </select>
   <br />

   <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select category</option>
   </select>
   <br />

   <select name="material" id="material" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select material</option>
   </select>
   <br />
    
   <select name="source_light" id="source_light" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select source_light</option>
   </select>
   <br />
    
   <select name="color_temperature" id="color_temperature" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select color_temperature</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: The answer is not in the code you've posted in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure but use `Switch` statement instead of multiple `if` and see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139989/13378977 this might be helpful for you

Comment: @KIKO Software Should I put a php file `fetch_filter2.php`?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @ Amaan warsi I will check.

Comment: @KIKO Software Firefox - network - test3 and test4 are not send to php file.

Comment: Are you checked your `Mysql Table`?

Answer (score 0):

Verify your drop down list under "action" class. As per your condition it won't trigger if your selected drop down item doesn't have value `if($(this).val() != '')`.

Also make sure your expected drop down items have the value *material* for your test3 and *source_light* for your test4

Another suggestion: To load and trigger dynamic change event for drop down you can use below jQuery API:

```
$(document).on("change", ".action", function(){
//Your code here
});
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then please share your HTML or drop down data.

Updated answer: I can see there is no class "action" in your select/drop down items for material, source_light and color_temperature. That is why change actions of these drop down items are not catching in your $('.action').change(function() ... code block.

Comment: I checked your suggestions but it's the same, I added html

Comment: Ok, I can see there is no class "action" in your select/drop down items for material, source_light and color_temperature. That is why change actions of these drop down items are not catching in your $('.action').change(function() ... code block.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I have looked at it so many times and not seen it. Works, write an official answers  if you want to approve.

Comment: Done. Updated my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.action').change(function() 
      {
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
       var action = $(this).attr("id");
       var query = $(this).val();
       var result = '';
        switch(action) {
         case "name":
          result = 'category';
          alert ('test1');
        break;
        case "category":
         result = 'material';
         alert ('test2');
        break;
       case "material":
        result = 'source_light';
        alert ('test3');
       break;
       case "source_light":
        result = 'color_temperature';
         alert ('test4');
        break;
        default:
         // result = 'color_temperature'; 
       }
          
       $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_filter2.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, query:query},
        success:function(data){
         $('#'+result).html(data);
        }
       })
      }
     });
    });
```

Comment: I checked your code but it's the same, I added html

Comment: in 15 minutes I will transfer it to www

Comment: I know that but I've looked at it so many times that I don't know where the error is.

Comment: No need to check `Jquery` problem is in your `HTML` part see this tutorial to debug your `HTML` code https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Use `action` class in options instead of `Select`

Comment: @ Amaan warsi  Link http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/staff/sagittarius/filter2.php

Comment: @Syriusz I inspected your page but there is no big error in your `JS` try to filter out your `PHP` file or `Mysql Table`

Comment: @Syriusz No need